# Couldn't find .dynsym while use ltrace

Tags: linux, debugging, ltrace

I have tried to attach to process(pid=1234) to watch all libraries call.

```
./ltrace-arm-static-0.7.91 -fp  1234
```

I got error:

```
 Couldn't find .dynsym or .dynstr in "/proc/1234/exe"
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

`ltrace` works by intercepting the calls to shared libraries. You have a fully-static binary which *doesn't use* any shared libraries, and that's what the error tells you.

`ltrace` is the wrong tool for whatever problem you are trying to solve.

> What can I do?

Start by reading http://xyproblem.info.

Then ask a new question about the *actual* problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: That process is not fully-static binary. I just want to see all the calls for share library.

Comment: @Kokomelom "that process is not fully-static" -- `ltrace` says it is. What's the output from `readelf -WS /proc/1234/exe`  and `cat /proc/1234/maps`?

Comment: `cat /proc/1234/maps` show me some libraries in `/lib` and readelf show me lot of sections include dynsym (type=DYNSYM)